# Dealing with the frustration of feeling taken for a ride

Tags: new-job

I switched into consulting after a few years on client's site. I was convinced by my now bosses to accept a position lower than what I did in the industry. the argument was: if you're good you will be promoted very quickly.

Now I'm in...

And I'm not impressed. I work with plenty of very young and quite arrogant managers who seem to lack basic project management and people management skills. And I'm getting more and more frustrated every day. My colleagues are very good at selling things (that's a very important skill - I'm not neglecting that!) but most lack expertise in our technical field and in managing people and projects.

The fact that I'm several years older than most managers and even some directors contributes to my frustration. I don't want to be ageist, but the reflection that they are incompetent and younger and still get paid more does frustrate me, no matter how much I fight this feeling.

Especially given that I need to do plenty of unpaid overtime because the processes they establish and their project management are so inefficient and chaotic.

Oh, and this promotion thing seems unrealistic judging by what I observe. Promotions don't happen frequently.

My frustration is growing every day.

I don't want to feel like that.

What is the best way to frame it to myself and others? What strategy should I take assuming I want to stay at the company - I changed my last job quite quickly, don't want to do that again.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to tell from your question what you would like the company to do differently.  If you came to me with this list of issues, I would have no idea why exactly you're unhappy.  You should identify specific things that are causing issues or that you'd like them to change, document them, and be prepared to propose solutions when discussing with your supervisor.  For example, when you say the processes and project management are inefficient and chaotic, that doesn't really describe the problem.  Are they changing priorities and requirements too frequently?  What's the real issue?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, https://www.google.com/search?biw=1438&bih=747&sxsrf=ACYBGNRVKKUvd7VlouCxkGbbIvwtGJfgOQ%3A1573855571327&ei=UyHPXbTXE8zHwQKe1omIAg&q=problem+framing&oq=problem+framing&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30j0l8.81590.84778..85214...0.3..0.158.994.3j6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i273j0i67.wcf8R9nhUy4&ved=0ahUKEwj0zIbynO3lAhXMY1AKHR5rAiE4ChDh1QMICw&uact=5

Comment: @user2152678: you may also want to take a look at your job selection strategy: Apparently you didn't stay long at your previous gig and now this one is going sour too. The best cure would be prevention: next time make really sure that the job and the company are what you really want to do before you sign on the dotted line.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I know to getting promoted is to switch jobs every 1 year or so. According to my coworkers, many of which of whom have been in the IT field for a bunch of years (5+), they mention being promoted in-house comes hard and at times there is literally no track to getting promoted.

This can happen with startups, but big companies generally do not have this issue. It is possible that a NEW branch of an established company does not have an established career progression track at that specific branch, so you might want to check if your office is new.

Now if you wish to stay at your current job and be promoted in-house, then you will have to identify who your critical persons of interest are, i.e., bosses with actual authority, and if you're confident enough, your bosses' boss! Impress these people by showing up to work on time everyday, doing your work properly and outperforming your peers.

There is one slight issue - sometimes if you're too good at your job, they won't want to promote you. Outperform your peers, but try doing it in such ways wherein it looks like you'd be a better fit in the upper level positions. People will definitely notice. Try it out! Try pointing out the flaws of these younger, less-experienced folk to other people and get people talking.

It's unfortunate you accepted a position below what you're capable of, and you'll need to make sure you don't make the same mistake again. You have to fight for a good job and preparing for that next interview is a never-ending process, even when you have scored your current job.

Answer (score 1):

> What strategy should I take assuming I want to stay at the company\

Excel and hope for the best. Worry less about what others are doing or making and focus on proactively making yourself into a promotion candidate rather than waiting for someone to notice you.

You don't do this by antagonising people above you, you do it by making it look as if promoting you will be a good move for them. So you be organised, you fix problems quickly and efficiently and remain cheerful and motivated. Don't be shy to let them know you want promotion either, by taking on more responsibility where possible and proving your worth.

Realistically you should be doing this anyway, your fatalistic outlook hurts no one but yourself, self confidence is half the battle, convince yourself you can do it first then follow through.